# Map same object multiple times with different ignore fields

Tags: java, dto, mapstruct

I would like to have a mapper like this, one method of the mapper should ignore the roles field.

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper
{
      UserDTO userToUserDTO( User user );

      @Mapping( target = "roles", ignore = true )
      UserDTO userToUserDTOWithoutRoles( User user );

 }
```

I have this error `Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping collection element to UserDTO` during compilation time. 
I don't want to create another DTO just for removing the roles field, I could add a default method, maybe there is a better solution...

Comment: On which method does the error occur? Which version of MapStruct are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 possibilities for the error:

**First: You have other mappers that depend on your `UserMapper`**

Or you have more methods that you are not showing. When you have a case like this MapStruct will try to use one of the defined methods for the mapping of your other methods.

I guess you want to have one method as the default and the other ones should either be used manually or explicitly. For that you will need to use MapStruct [`@Named`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Named.html) / [`@Qualifier`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Qualifier.html) with [`Mapping#qualifiedByName`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapping.html#qualifiedByName--) / [`Mapping#qualifiedBy`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapping.html#qualifiedBy--).

Your mapper will need to look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    @Named("detailedUser")
    UserDTO userToUserDTO( User user );

    @Mapping( target = "roles", ignore = true )
    UserDTO userToUserDTOWithoutRoles( User user );
}
```

If you have this then all other Mappers that use your `UserMapper` will use `userToUserDTOWithoutRoles` per default. In order to use the other method you will need to do something like:

```
@Mapper(uses = { UserMapper.class})
public interface OtherMapper {

    @Mapping( source = "user", target = "user", qualifiedByName = "detailedUser")
    OtherDTO map( Other other );
}
```

Have a look at [Mapping methods based on qualifiers](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers) for more information about this.

**Second: You have a `Iterable` / `Map` of users in your `User`**

This can also be solved with the first approach. However, here you have a cyclic dependency so try out the new `@Context` from 1.2.0. Have a look at [mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles) example.

**Third you are using 1.2.0 and some bean in your `User` has a reference to the `User`.**

If this is the case then in the generated class MapStruct will try to generate a mapping method between the beans and MapStruct will look for a method that it can use to map the `User`s in the bean and will result in `Ambiguous mapping methods...`.

The solution of this is the same as the second one.

Comment: I have another method `List<User> userDTOsToUsers( List<UserDTO> userDTOs );` which should use the method `UserDTO userToUserDTO( User user );`. If I add `UserDTO userToUserDTOWithoutRoles( User user );` I think the implementation doesn't know if it should use `userToUserDTO` or `userToUserDTOWithoutRoles`, maybe adding a qualifier will help

Comment: What should other mappers that use the `UserMapper` use? And yes adding a qualifier is the right approach. Once you tell me what the other mappers should use I will update my answer. Can you also update your question to include the `List`?